# How can I split data coming from JSON?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, json, data

In my recent project, I'm working with Arduino and JSON. Now, I get data from JSON and I can able to receive in Arduino side.

Below one is my Arduino code:

```
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

String response = "";
bool begin = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop()
{

  while(Serial.available() || !begin)
  {
    char in = Serial.read();

    if (in == '{')
    {
      begin = true;
    }

    if(begin) response += (in);

    if(in == '}')
    {
        break;
    }
    delay(1);
  }

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(response);
}
```

Output :

```
{"TPS":"0.40","MAP":"1.05","LOAD":"14"}
```

Now, I want to split data means store `0.40` in one variable, `1.05` in another variable and `14` in another variable. I don't know how to split this.

Comment: Try this: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2017/04/08/splitting-up-text-in-c/

Comment: Can try this JSON library: https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson

Comment: @goddland_16 I try out that library but I face one problem.

Comment: if you know the number of variables and it is fixed, and the order of incoming data, you can parse yourself. Well, I can parse the example string provided all the above conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it. I have fixed length of data. So, I use a counter to calculate the how many characters are there in my data. Now using the index of this characters, I find out proper data and then store in a different variable.

Below is my code:

```
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

String responseOne = "";
String responseTwo = "";
String responseThree = "";
bool begin = false;

int counter = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop()
{

  while(Serial.available() || !begin)
  {
    char in = Serial.read();

    if (in == '{')
    {
      begin = true;
    }

    if(begin)
    {
      counter++;

      if(counter >= 9 && counter <= 12)   // This gives 0.40
      {
        responseOne += (in);              // 0.40 store in responseOne variable
      }

      if(counter >= 22 && counter <= 25)  // This gives 1.05
      {
        responseTwo += (in);              // 1.05 store in responseTwo
      }

      if(counter >= 36 && counter <= 37)  // This gives 14
      {
        responseThree += (in);            // 14 store in responseThree
      }
    }

    if(in == '}')
    {
        break;
    }
    delay(1);
  }

  float newResponseOne = responseOne.toFloat();  // Convert string into Float
  float newResponseTwo = responseTwo.toFloat();  // Convert string into Float
  int newResponseThree = responseThree.toInt();  // Convert string into Integer

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(newResponseOne);

  lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
  lcd.print(newResponseTwo);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(newResponseThree);
}
```